# properly parameterize mysqli query and print multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, while-loop

I know this question if floating just about everywhere but I can't seem to apply it to my own problem.
I have been using non parameterized queries which makes my project extremely vulnerable to SQL injection

**Plot:**

I have a form where you enter a date.
PHP will get the date and use it in a query to retrieve multiple rows of information.

How do I parametize my mysqli queries and print out the multiple rows? This is what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <label for="fromDate" class="control-label">Date from:</label>
    <input type="date" id="fromDate" class="datepicker" name="searchDate" value="<?php echo $searchDate; ?>">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Go</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="formIdentifier" value="mainSearch" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if($_POST['formIdentifier'] == "mainSearch"){
    //get date from form
    $searchDate = $_POST['searchDate'];
    $todayDateFrom = $searchDate." 00:00:00";
    $todayDateTo = $searchDate." 23:59:59";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT G.* FROM Groups AS G, Customers AS C 
            WHERE C.travel_Date >= '?'
            AND   C.travel_Date <= '?'
            AND C.customer_ID = G.leader_ID");
    $stmt->bind_param("si", todayDateFrom , todayDateTo );
    $stmt->execute();
    /* bind variables to prepared statement */
    $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);
}
```

**PHP loop**

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //Display copious amounts of data.
}
```

I have based my code from the PHP manual and ended up getting overwhelmed. I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track in preparing my queries let alone attempting how to display the data. Any help would be appreciated!

note - if someone could explain `$stmt->bind_param("si", todayDateFrom , todayDateTo );` specifically the "si" that would be fantastic. I just don't understand what its purpose is.

**--SOLUTION--**

Thanks to all the answers I was able to get my first parameterized query to work.

As suggested, I removed the " ' " that was surrounding " ? " in my query.

I then changed the `bind_param` "si" to "ss" because i was binding 2 strings, not a string and an integer.

I then binded the results (in this example I have 3 columns in the table)

```
$stmt->bind_result($group_ID, $leader_ID, $gDate);
```

Because I don't currently have a 3rd party driver installed, I had to display the results like so:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "group_ID: ".$group_ID."<br />";
    echo "leader_ID: ".$leader_ID."<br />";
    echo "group_Date: ".$group_Date."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing code works just fine, except you have one tiny mistake, from the manual [PHP MySQLi bind_param manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

**i**   corresponding variable has type integer

**d**   corresponding variable has type double

**s**   corresponding variable has type string

So from above we can see that, "i" is used if you want to tell the MySQLi that your parameter is in fact integer, and "s" is used if you want to tell MySQLi that your paramater is in fact an string.

So please replace

```
$stmt->bind_param("si", todayDateFrom , todayDateTo );
```

with

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", todayDateFrom , todayDateTo );
```

and remove

> '

from the parameter place holders (i.e '?' should be replaced with ?)

And your code of sending the parameterized statement will work just fine

**Fetching the results**

From the manual [PHP MySQLi fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) what fetch does is:

> Fetch results from a prepared statement into the bound variables

What you are looking for is [get_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php). From the manual it:

> Gets a result set from a prepared statement

So you can fetch the data using the following code:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        foreach ($row as $r)
        {
            print "$r ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
```

Here is the documentation for [fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: Thankyou for your comprehensive answer. I have made the required changes but now I get the error "Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()" It doesn't like the line "$result = $stmt->get_result();" Apparently a google search tells me I need to install a 3rd party driver in order to use it. Is that the case? Or is there another way I can print out the results?

Comment: I ended up using $stmt->bind_result and printed it using $stmt->fetch in a while loop

Comment: if your problem is solved then gr8! :), otherwise if you have access to php.ini, you can just un-comment the line: extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll from PHP.ini and restart apache and mysql.

Comment: I might do this in the future. Thanks heaps again for your answer. Really got me unstuck and now I'm onto my next error!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change following line:

```
$stmt->bind_param("si", todayDateFrom , todayDateTo );
```

To:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", todayDateFrom , todayDateTo );
```

*Reason:* If you look at the following image you can see that `i` is for `Integer` and `s` is for `String`.

[image]

The date parameter should be provided as `String`, hence use `s`.

Reference: PHP [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) documentations.

Also you need to update your SQL statement:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT G.* FROM Groups AS G, Customers AS C 
        WHERE C.travel_Date >= '?'
        AND   C.travel_Date <= '?'
        AND C.customer_ID = G.leader_ID");
```

To:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT G.* FROM Groups AS G, Customers AS C 
        WHERE C.travel_Date >= ?
        AND   C.travel_Date <= ?
        AND C.customer_ID = G.leader_ID");
```

*Reason:* Parameter mark should not be surrounded by `'`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity. I didn't see the specs on the website! But now that i've made the amendments i'm getting a "Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement" does this indicate that I have something wrong in my query now?

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->bind_param("si", todayDateFrom , todayDateTo );
```

During param bind you are mentioning that first varible is string and 2nd is integer but as per your code it should be

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $todayDateFrom , $todayDateTo );
```

Please remove single quotes from your query as well and should be something like this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT G.* FROM Groups AS G, Customers AS C 
            WHERE C.travel_Date >= ?
            AND C.travel_Date <= ?
            AND C.customer_ID = G.leader_ID");
```

Comment: That makes so much more sense. My problem now that i amended it is

 " Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in" which refers to line 48 a.k.a 

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $todayDateFrom, $todayDateTo);

Comment: Can you please remove single quotes from your query where `?` check my updated answer as well

Comment: I didn't down vote.. I upvoted as your answer helped me troubleshoot further :)

Comment: @AkiraDawson, not you but someone down voted me. Thanks, I glad my answer helps you to troubleshoot your issue.